# Switching the column and row of a matrix with the next one inJava

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I was trying to switch the rows and columns of a matrix with the next one in java and for some reason for some of the positions the results i get are right and for other they aren´t. Is this the correct way of making the changes in the matrix or does this code wrong in some way?

```
public static  void intercambiar(int[][] vector,int i, int j) {
        for (int k = 0; k < vector.length; k++) {
            int temp = vector[k][j];
            vector[k][j] = vector[k][i];
            vector[k][i] = temp;

            temp = vector[j][k];
            vector[j][k] = vector[i][k];
            vector[i][k] = temp;
        }

    }
```

Just to clarify, the code should be able to switch all the rows of the first column with all the rows of the second column and then switch all the columns of the first row with the columns of the second row.

Comment: Edit your post and show an example (not images) of an original matrix and a matrix with the results you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

> ... I was trying to switch the rows and columns of a matrix with the next one ...

For reference, in *[mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics)* this is referred to as a *[transposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose)*. Here is a relevant *Wikipedia* article: *[Wikipedia – In-place matrix transposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition)*.

Here is an example for a *[square matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_matrix)*:

```java
<T> void transpose(T[][] a) {
    T t;
    int m, n, z = a.length;
    for (m = 0; m < z; m++)
        for (n = m + 1; n < z; n++) {
            t = a[m][n];
            a[m][n] = a[n][m];
            a[n][m] = t;
        }
}
```

Output

```
before
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]

after
[1, 4, 7]
[2, 5, 8]
[3, 6, 9]
```

And, here is an example for a *[rectangular matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics))*:

```java
<T> T[][] transpose(T[][] a) {
    int m, n, x = a[0].length, y = a.length;
    Class<?> t = a.getClass().getComponentType().getComponentType();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[][] b = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(t, x, y);
    for (m = 0; m < y; m++)
        for (n = 0; n < x; n++)
            b[n][m] = a[m][n];
    return b;
}
```

Output

```
before
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5, 6]
[7, 8]

after
[1, 3, 5, 7]
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```